# React-Router-Dom V6 Nested URL Not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Can I get help actually i upgraded my react-router-dom to V6
So i fixed the main url
It works but the url with nested link doesn't

Example
/about works
But
/about-item/1 doesn't[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUZNI.jpg)

Code :

Comment: <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/service"}`} 
element={<ServicePage />}             />
<Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/service-details/:id"}`} element={<ServiceDetails />}/>

Comment: Add the code to the question section

Comment: You need to add your actual code instead of an image plus the exact issue you are having.

Comment: I don't see any nested routed in that image. Please clarify what "nested URL" means for you specifically in this case. Please also update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you are trying to do. Please provide detail about what isn't working, other than "it's not working".

Answer (score -3, accepted):

1. First you can uninstall.
   -**npm uninstall react-router-dom**
2. Install this version.
   -**npm install react-router-dom@5.2.0**

Comment: I dont wana degrade the the dependencies

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like that:

```
              <Route
                path="service"
                element={<ServicePage />}
              >
                <Route
                  path="service-details/:id"
                  element={<ServiceDetails />}
                />
                <Route
                  path="service-details/new"
                  element={<ServiceDetails />}
                />  
             </Route>
```

And don't forget to use `<Outlet/>` tag in the ServicePage component